# Dagger2 can provide on Presenter layer but null on Model layer

Tags: android, mvp

I'm trying to refactor my app using MVP pattern and Dagger 2 for Dependency Injection.

I Create module that provides Application Context and I want get Context to get `SharedPreferences` on Model Layer.

I inject Context on Presenter layer and it's working with `SharedPreference`, but when I move to Model layer, Dagger inject a `null` value on `Context` variable.

**Inject**

```
@Inject
public Context mContext;
```

**App Module**

AppModule provides Application Context

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private App app;

    public AppModule(App app){
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    public Context providesApp(){
        return app.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .mainModule(new MainModule())
                .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

**App Component**

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class,MainModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(LoginActivity activity);
}
```

**Main Module**

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    public MainContract.Model providesMainModel(){
        return new MainModel();
    }

    @Provides
    public LoginContract.Model providesLoginModel(){
        return new LoginModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://medium.com/@m_mirhoseini/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Comment: @MohsenMirhoseiniArgi I've read those article and GitHub repo before I ask on SO. Thanks for your great article and sample :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the `Context` in your App Module, you can add the `Context` as parameter to `LoginModel` constructor.

```
@Provides
public LoginContract.Model providesLoginModel(Context contect){
   return new LoginModel(contect);
}

@Provides
public LoginContract.Presenter providesLoginPresenter(LoginContract.Model model){
   return new LoginPresenter(model);
}
```

But bear in mind that you must use `android` packages only on your Activities and Fragments for easy testing. So your approach is wrong.

**EDIT**

Well for me, the best option is to create a class for SharedPreferences like this

```
public class Preferences {
   private final SharedPreferences preferences;
   private String key;
   private String defaultValue;

   public StringPreferences(@NonNull SharedPreferences preferences) {
     this.preferences = preferences;
   }

   @Nullable
   public String get(String mykey) {
     return preferences.getString(mykey, defaultValue);
   }

   public void set(@NonNull String mykey, @Nullable String value) {
     preferences.edit().putString(mykey, value).apply();
   }

   // same way for integers, longs, doubles and booleans

   public boolean isSet() {
     return preferences.contains(key);
   }

   public void delete() {
    preferences.edit().remove(key).apply();
   }
}
```

Then in App Module I `Provide` the `SharedPreferences`

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Preferences providePreferences(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    return new Preferences(prefs);
}
```

Finally in Main Module

```
@Provides
public LoginContract.Model providesLoginModel(Preferences prefs){
   return new LoginModel(prefs);
}

@Provides
public LoginContract.Presenter providesLoginPresenter(LoginContract.Model model){
   return new LoginPresenter(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I just moved from "Spaghetti Code" to MVP approach. I just want to modify Shared preferences from Model layer, and shared preferences need context. Anny suggestion?

Comment: Glad I helped! :)